# I keep getting the same error while trying to create a field type DOUBLE in SQL

Tags: sql, database, ssms

```
create table test(isaNumber DOUBLE)
```

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

But if i type `create table test(isaNumber INT)` no errors appear

Comment: Since when SQL Server has `DOUBLE` type???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double` is not a valid data type in `sqlserver`, use `float` instead. See

[list of data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

in sql server.

```
create table test7(isaNumber float)
```